# mysql select from multiple tables but no join

Tags: mysql

I have several separate tables defined in my (in construction) database that shares the same fields. But also in database, I have other tables that aren't related to data, so to differentiate, I mark some of them with the same comment 'data_table'.

It is useful in procedures:

select table_name from information_schema.tables where table_schema = 'myDB' and table_comment = 'data_table'

I need to do a select over all tables marked with this comment, to obtain something like, but not using JOIN because every time I have to add more table names in that select.

ID          Value

CAP-001     0.1uF          <-- from capacitor table

### CAP-002     1nF

RES-001     1k             <-- from resistor table

### RES-002     100k

```
                       <-- from other table in the future
```

It is possible? Thank you very much for suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why this would be a good idea, but I think you can solve your problem by doing multiple queries using a `UNION` statement. Read the syntax in the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [UNION](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html) statements.

> UNION is used to combine the result from multiple SELECT statements
>   into a single result set.
>
> The column names from the first SELECT statement are used as the
>   column names for the results returned. Selected columns listed in
>   corresponding positions of each SELECT statement should have the same
>   data type. (For example, the first column selected by the first
>   statement should have the same type as the first column selected by
>   the other statements.)

```
mysql> SELECT REPEAT('a',1) UNION SELECT REPEAT('b',10);
+---------------+
| REPEAT('a',1) |
+---------------+
| a             |
| bbbbbbbbbb    |
+---------------+


(SELECT a FROM t1 WHERE a=10 AND B=1 ORDER BY a LIMIT 10)
UNION
(SELECT a FROM t2 WHERE a=11 AND B=2 ORDER BY a LIMIT 10);
```